# JavaLite Http exception handling

Tags: java, httprequest

Anybody used this before? http://javalite.io/http

I am wondering how the exception is handled. For example, when I call Http.get(), what if connection timeout, etc?

Comment: I'm not familiar with it.  Have you tried reaching out on their mailing list or looking through their sources or java docs?  They don't even seem to have published javadocs on their site(though there appears to be a maven javadoc jar), so it might be worthwhile to consider a more active and mature library.

Comment: @Taylor I just got the reply from them, they told me that all exception thrown is RuntimeException.